# horizontal line with dots between them

Tags: html, css

Can I achieve this without using `<hr>`?
I want the horizontal and vertical lines with the dots.
[This is what I did for the horizontal one and it doesn't look nice](http://jsfiddle.net/fwqSH/326/) am not sure how to do the vertical one even. Add a fiddle please.

[image]

```
<div class="horizontaltop" runat="server"></div>
<div align="center">...</div>
<div class="horizontalRule" runat="server"></div>
```

```
div.horizontaltop{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#d1d1d1;
    height:1px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
div.horizontalRule{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#d1d1d1;
    height:1px;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

Comment: Without using `hr` and `css`. Not possible. Would be possible without hr but with css though

Comment: I meant without using `hr`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward with pseudo elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/Es4wY/1/

```
<div class="dotted-border">Your content</div>

.dotted-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.dotted-border:after {
    border-top: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    content: "\2022\2022\2022";
    display: block;
    font-size: 8px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Edit - here's a vertical one. The css is not quite as pretty, but it works.
http://jsfiddle.net/b5U5M/1/

```
.dotted-border-vertical {
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.dotted-border-vertical:after {
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    content: "\2022\A\2022\A\2022";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 8px;
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 0.8;
    padding-top: 80px;
    position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: +1 ... and now a vertical one! ;) (kidding... don't do it... it's insane!)

Comment: As I think about this more, this might be a good case to use CSS3 border images. Someone who has more experience with that than me can try to come up with a solution.

Comment: No, not good, if the content height increases you're screwed! Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/b5U5M/1/ **Design should not be compromised by content. Remember.**

Comment: I could do it... you could do it too! It's easy.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, it is possible to expand the border to the content height using position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; I'm not sure how to vertically center the dots using that method, though.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class `dots` to the center div, and add the following CSS:

```
div.dots {
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #aaa;   
  width: 20px;
}
```

That will give you more authentic dots, and you can mess with the sizing and color. You'll then want to wrap `.dots` in a parent `div` that centers it.